# Redshift Loading Data - Cannot create table with Value 1-127 Error

Tags: database, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am trying to create a redshift serverless db with some weather data that I have in a csv file located in a bucket. The weather data is in a clean csv format from IBM, that i extract through an API so it is clean.
When im trying load data from the bucket where i have uploaded the csv file i keep receive the error "The Value must be 1-127 characters" [error from load data redshift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYd4o.png)

It is also failing for a simple weather station data [simple data failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rKwM.png)

From what I have read online, the value must be between 1-127 characters which the data values definingly are, the latitude has a "-" to indicate a negative value, but if i remove this it still comes up with an error, and the raw latitude data is not in the bulk weather data file.

Comment: By "load" are you COPYing into the database or using spectrum?  This error message appears to be indicating that an identifier is too long.  Redshift identifiers can only be 1 - 127 ascii characters in length.  Does this align with what you are seeing?

Comment: If not please provide more info on what you are doing - commands, full DDL, exact error messages, etc.  Also your DDL looks a little off as well - latitude is varchar, longitude is double.